# Calculate 2 years before date in Jenkins

Tags: date, jenkins, build

I wanted to do an automation in Jenkins like it needs to compare today's date and it should go to 2 years back with same date and month. For example, if today is May 1 2021 then it should return a result as May 1 2019.

I have checked Build timestamp plugin in Jenkins, but how to calculate 2 years before for same date & month ?
Could someone kindly confirm how can we make such changes in Jenkins ? Thanks!

Comment: does this work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and execute a shell script as below which will give you 2 years before date :

```
# !/usr/bin/bash
getdate=`date +%d/%m/%Y -d "2 year ago"`
echo "$getdate"
```

**Output**:
27/05/2019

In Jenkinsfile you could use:

```
def ret = sh(script: 'date +%d/%m/%Y -d "2 year ago"', returnStdout: true)
```